# C# Dapper How to know query is correct

Tags: c#, dapper

I am making a login form using dapper library something is wrong here i cant seem to make it to work even if the password or username is wrong it opens up new form

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your usernmae.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            txtUsername.Focus();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var data = db.Query("select Username,Password from UserLog", commandType: CommandType.Text);
                if ((data.SingleOrDefault() !=null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have been succesfully logged in.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    FormHome frm= new FormHome();
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Username or Password is Incorrect.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at the data content, and why `data.SingleOrDefault() !=null` always true.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply sending this query to the database so it will return results every time irrespective of the login info:

```
select Username, Password from UserLog
```

So of course it will pass since you are not filtering the records. As long as you have 1 record in the database, it will pass.

You need to send the user login info and check if a record exists with the login info for the current user that you are trying to authenticate:

```
IEnumerable users = db
    .Query("select Username, Password from UserLog where UserName = @UserName and Password = @Password",
    new {UserName = txtUsername.Text, Password = // put the password here});
if (users.Any())
{
    // authenticated so do whatever
}
```